# css() function call failing silently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a strange problem with the css() function. Here's my code snippet.

```
console.log('' + $(this).css('left') + ':' + $(this).css('top'));
console.log('Desired position - ' + return_to_left + ':' + return_to_top);
$(this).css('top', return_to_top + 'px');
$(this).css('left', return_to_left + 'px');
console.log('Finally: ' + $(this).css('left') + ':' + $(this).css('top'));
```

The output I get on the console is this.

```
458px:2113px
Desired position - 448px:2102px;
Finally: 458px:2113px;
```

Could anyone suggest why this might be happening? I have tried experimenting with '!important'. Doesn't help.

(Also, for context, this code is part of a callback function after an animation. It tries to position the element back to where it was before animation began.)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem!!

This:

```
console.log('Desired position - ' + return_to_left + ':' + return_to_top);
```

Outputs...

```
Desired position - 448px:2102px;
```

therefore your variables `return_to_left` and `return_to_top` ALREADY have the `px` string at the end.

Your css call looks like this:

```
$(this).css('top', '448pxpx');
$(this).css('left', '2102pxpx');
```

Which won't work! :p Remove the `+ 'px'` from the end of the css calls.

Comment: Thanks! :) That was obvious... Dammit!

Comment: lol no worries. As I helped you you might want to press the little tick next to the answer to mark it as the correct answer. If you do this it helps others coming for the same issue and increases your credibility on the site if you want to ask more questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

return_to_left and return_to_top already includes 'px' but you are appending it a second time.

```
$(this).css('top', return_to_top );
$(this).css('left', return_to_left );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code you posted.
It worked.

Is it possible that in your variables return_to_left and return_to_top already a "px" is?

i put this in the variable:

```
return_to_left = 100;
```

it worked.
I think your content will be saved dynamic.
So if you load the infos via
    $(this).css('left')

then there will be already a "px"

try this code instead of yours:

```
$(this).css('top', return_to_top);
$(this).css('left', return_to_left);
```

i dont know your complete code but maybe this will resolve your problem